# How to align pivot points with pivot points of different objects

Tags: modeling, rigging

Here are two objects.

Both now have the pivot point at the center of the object.

[image]

I want to move the pivot point of the second object to the pivot point of the first object.

How can do it?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 3D cursor to set your object origin.

1. Select your desired object, <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> to **set cursor to selected**.

[image]

2. Select back your object, search **set origin** (or menu > object > set origin). **Origin to 3D Cursor**

[image]

Comment: Worth mentioning at step 2, can select multiple objects to move all their origins to cursor.